# Prove that this algorithm generates the characteristic sequence of primes.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that the characteristic function of primes is generated by this algorithm:

$$T(1,1)=1$$
$$n=k: \;\; T(n,k)=1$$
$$\mod(n,k)=0: \;\; -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} T(n,k+i)$$
$$k=1: \;\; T(n,1)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} T(n,k+i)$$
$$\text{else} \; \; T(n,k)=0$$

This is a table starting:

$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$$

Where the characteristic sequence of primes is found in the first column.

```
(*Mathematica start*)
(*Recurrence*)
 nn = 104; 
 Clear[t]; t[1, 1] = 1; 
 t[n_, k_] := 
 t[n, k] = 
 If[k == 1, Sum[t[n, k + i], {i, 1, n - 1}], 
 If[Mod[n, k] == 0, If[n == k, 1, -Sum[t[n, k + i], {i, 1, n - 1}]], 
 0], 0];
 MatrixForm[Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]];
 a = Table[t[n, 1], {n, 1, nn}] (*Mats Granvik,May 31 2015*) 
 (*a*Range[nn]*)
 (*end*)
```

$$1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...$$

$$1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 19, ...$$

Comment: How is $T(n,k)$ defined if $k\neq 1$, and $k$ is not a divisor of $n$?

Comment: Oh, thanks for that comment. I forgot to mention that it is zero.

Comment: It's also not clear what that sequence at the bottom is supposed to be - $T$ is not a sequence, since it has two parameters.

Comment: Yes that is correct, it is a table where the sequence is the first column.

Comment: Now when I think about your comment I realize it is not a recurrence.

Comment: The function you describe at the start does not really match your Mathematica; for example, the description implies that $T(2,1)$ should be computed using the third line, while your code computes it using the fourth line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k$ is the largest factor of $n$ between $1$ and $n$, then $T(n,k)=-1$.  That forces all the smaller factors of $n$, $T(n,h)=1-1=0$ including $T(n,1)=0$.
If there is no factor of $n$ between $1$ and $n$, then $T(n,1)=1$.